# Uncaught Throwable java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createArrayOf

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, datasource

I getting below error while trying to call con.createArrayOf method on Microsoft SQL server with datasource pool connection

Uncaught Throwable
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;

Any lead would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't use the createArrayOf method with your current library. You'll have to use a different database driver library.

You could use something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server since you're using SQL Server.

Comment: Apache DBCP is not a driver library, it is a connection pool library.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you are using Apache DBCP 1.3 or older, as the method you are trying to call was introduced in JDBC 4 (Java 6), while Apache DBCP 1.3 supports JDBC 3 (Java 1.4/5).

Given the overview at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ you need to use at minimum Apache DBCP 1.4, or a newer version (the latest is 2.7.0, for Java 8 and higher).

Note though that upgrading won't help you much, because the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver implementation of `createArrayOf` will throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` as SQL Server doesn't support arrays.